# Android - onPause / onWindowFocusChanged are not called when entering a notification

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-mediaplayer, navigationbar

I have a MediaPlayer which runs from my main activity. I stop it on onPause.

The problem is that when I click on something from the notification bar (for example, a whatsapp message), onPause is not called and I can't stop the music.

I tried stopping it using onWindowFocusChanged, but that as well is not being called when entering an app from the bar.

How can I stop the music in this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: that shouldn't be the case, the onPause should get called when you go to other activities via onPause(), can you put a log there and check ?

Comment: @dumb_terminal I did check, I also tried to debug to see what happens and it didn't even reach there.

Comment: can you post some minimal code snippet ?